# Where Visual Studio Extnesions DialogPage are stored?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I'm developing a Visual Studio extension for Visual Studio 2017. In my extension, I have a class inheriting DialogPage to allow the user to define parameters.

I want to see exactly what gets serialized when settings are changed.

According to [Options and Options Pages article in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166553.aspx#Anchor_1) the data should be stored in the registry but I couldn't find it.

Where are the settings are stored for Visual Studio options page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to following blog, VS2017 support multiple instances of VS install on the same machine. So the settings were moved out of the registry. **Each instance also has its own private registry so they can be configured independently.**

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2016/09/15/changes-to-visual-studio-15-setup/

You could find the private registry for your Visual Studio 2017 from C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_XXX**Exp** ("XXX "could be any numbers, just find the folder suffix is "Exp").

And you could open this settings file with regedit.exe. Detailed steps, please refer to:
http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/2016/11/23/some-implications-of-the-new-modular-setup-of-visual-studio-2017-for-vsx-developers/